# How did my work profile get on my phone?

Tags: uninstallation, work-profiles

This is a personal device.  Its never been tied to any employer. I've only had it around 6 months, purchased through carrier website, outright/ unlocked. I'm absolutely lost and I cannot uninstall. It just tells me I can't preform that and to contact my admim.

Comment: Could you check the Account settings and see if there's any account registered to the work profile? Otherwise, are you using an app (e.g. Island) to create parallel space (using work profile) for installing same apps on the same device?